# Concat values from same column name in "one" dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I want to concat the values if they have same columns.

[image]
I've found some solutions that are from different dataframe, but not from one dataframe.
Also, I tried to separate columns to single dataframe then concat, but it seems not working because the columns' name are shown differently. (For example, it shows "apple", "banana", "pizza", "apple.1", "banana.1"...)

Is there any solution to show like this? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get  faster recommendations from the community

Comment: what have been you trying to get your desired result?

Comment: @RF1991 Hey, did you see the images? I've posted my desired result one the post

Comment: I can see,however using text and table would be much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt` to flatten your dataframe then `pivot` to reshape it as its original shape:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[0]

out = df.melt().assign(index=lambda x: x.groupby('variable').cumcount()) \
        .pivot_table('value', 'index', 'variable', fill_value=0) \
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)[df.columns.unique()]

print(out)

# Output
   apple  banana  pizza
0      1       4      4
1      2       3      7
2      3       2      3
3      5       0      1
4      8       0      5
5      9       0     34
```

Comment: Hey, it sounds great! But I found that my column name would show apple.1 and banana.1, so apple and apple.1 cannot concat. Do you know how to prevent rename the columns automatically? Thanks a lot

Comment: When you use `read_csv` and `read_excel`, column with same names are renamed (`mangle_dupe_cols` parameter). I will update my answer soon

Comment: I think it should work now :) I prepend `.melt()` by `rename(...)`

Comment: Hey! I've one more question. Is there any method to make the column names not ordering by the alphabet instead of ordering them. I want them to show what appears first and next (EX: apple, pizza, banana is the original data ordering, but it shows apple, banana, pizza instead.)

Comment: In your example the order is apple, banana, pizza ;-)

Comment: Actually, my dataset is not this food haha.

Comment: But I did the same way to my code. (just change the data

Comment: Use `cols = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[0].unique().tolist()` and at the end `out[cols]`

Comment: Do you mean to replace ```(columns=lambda x: x.rsplit('.')[0]) ``` to `cols = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[0].unique().tolist()`